# Regex only match if line has no characters besides dash

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to match and replace a line that has a `-` (dash) with only spaces or a line break after it, as in "`_ -_ _ _ _`" or "`- _ _ _`" or "`_ _ _ _ - _`", but not "`_ _ _ _ - _ asdf`" or "`- _ _ _ whatever`". It WOULD match if the letters came before, as in "`_ asdf _ _ - _ _ _`"

I am running it inside of a textarea, but I keep replacing all instances of `-`.

```
$('textarea[name="yaml"]').val(
    $('textarea[name="yaml"]').val().replace(/-\x20(?!.)/g,
      ""));           
}
```

I also tried `-\x20(?!\w \d)` and `-\x20[^.]`, among other combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `/-[\W]*$/m`? Change the `*` to a `+` if it needs at least one whitespace.

Comment: I think \W will match punctuation as well.

Answer (score 0):

`"^.*- +$"`

Note: This assumes you really only want spaces and not whitespace "\s"

Sample code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p>Click the button to replace "blue" with "red" in the paragraph below:</p>

  <p id="demo1">testing -</p>
  <p id="demo2">testing -</p>
  <p id="demo3">testing-</p>
  <p id="demo4">-</p>
  <p id="demo5">testing -</p>
  <p id="demo6">testing - tester</p>
  <p id="demo7">testing -tester</p>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      for (var i = 1; i <= 7; ++i) {
        var ele = "demo" + i;

        var str = document.getElementById(ele).innerHTML;
        var res = str.replace(/^.*- +$/gi, "!replaced!");
        document.getElementById(ele).innerHTML = res;
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading the question right, could be done like this.

```
 # /^(?=[\S\s])[\sa-z]*[\s-]*$/

 ^                      # BOS
 (?= [\S\s] )           # Ensure string not empty
 [\sa-z]*               # Optional whitespaces or letters
 [\s-]*                 # Optional whitespace or dash, but nothing else
 $                      # EOS
```